# Nodejs how to check independently a process is running by PID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm using `child_process` to spawn a child process and get return PID from it. I need to manage this child process by its PID. Below is my code:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');

let options = ['/c', arg1, arg2];

const myProcess = childProcess.spawn('cmd.exe', options, {
    detached: false,
    shell: false
});

let pid = myProcess.pid;
```

During run time, I want to use PID to **validate independently from outside** if the process is running or not (finished / killed). I want to know how to do this and what is the best way to make this validation in Nodejs?. I'm running application in Windows environment.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255202/checking-if-a-child-process-is-running

Comment: @A.M.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255202/checking-if-a-child-process-is-running is not my expected answer. I want to validate process from outside not listen `exit` event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out a solution as suggestion of [is-running](https://npmjs.org/package/is-running) module. But I don't want to install new module into my project just for this purpose, so I created my own `checkRunning()` function as below:

```js
// Return true if process following pid is running
checkRunning(pid) {
    try {
        return process.kill(pid, 0);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return error.code === 'EPERM';
    }
}
```

Following the Nodejs document about [process.kill(pid[, signal])](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal), I can use `process.kill()` to check the existence of process with specific `signal` argument is value 0 (not killing process as function name).

I make a copy of the document said:

> As a special case, a signal of 0 can be used to test for the existence of a process

Answer (score 2):

Probably this will help, npm module called **is-running** https://npmjs.org/package/is-running as was mentioned here - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884949/7927724

Comment: Thanks I will look at it

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but I don't want to install `is-running` module just for this check. My solution is just applying `process.kill` method. Thanks for your help, I will vote it up

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when a child process exits, you can check the [`exit` event](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit)

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'my.bat']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank @A. M. but this is not my expected answer. I want to validate process from outside independently, not listening `exit` event

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code fragment as a reference

```
win32 (cond) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const cmd = 'WMIC path win32_process get Name,Processid,ParentProcessId,Commandline,ExecutablePath'
      const lines = []

      const proc = utils.spawn('cmd', ['/c', cmd], { detached: false, windowsHide: true })
      proc.stdout.on('data', data => {
        lines.push(data.toString())
      })
      proc.on('close', code => {
        if (code !== 0) {
          return reject(new Error('Command \'' + cmd + '\' terminated with code: ' + code))
        }
        let list = utils.parseTable(lines.join('\n'))
          .filter(row => {
            if ('pid' in cond) {
              return row.ProcessId === String(cond.pid)
            } else if (cond.name) {
              if (cond.strict) {
                return row.Name === cond.name || (row.Name.endsWith('.exe') && row.Name.slice(0, -4) === cond.name)
              } else {
                // fix #9
                return matchName(row.CommandLine || row.Name, cond.name)
              }
            } else {
              return true
            }
          })
          .map(row => ({
            pid: parseInt(row.ProcessId, 10),
            ppid: parseInt(row.ParentProcessId, 10),
            // uid: void 0,
            // gid: void 0,
            bin: row.ExecutablePath,
            name: row.Name,
            cmd: row.CommandLine
          }))
        resolve(list)
      })
    })
  },
```

which come from https://github.com/yibn2008/find-process/blob/master/lib/find_process.js

Comment: Thank @sinbar. but this is not my expected answer. I want to validate process from outside independently, not listening `close` event

Comment: That's not listen `close` event, the point is  `'WMIC path win32_process get Name,Processid,ParentProcessId,Commandline,ExecutablePath'`.It spawn a `cmd` process and run a shell command in it and get the output: `proc.stdout.on('data', data => {
        lines.push(data.toString())
      })`

Comment: Oh, I don't want to listen output from `data` event also

Answer (score 0):

For the related subject here the best packages

#### Check only by pid

https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-running

#### Search by pid, name patterns and different means packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-process

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node

https://github.com/sindresorhus/process-exists