# Is that possible to kill the child process in Node.js by new HTTP request

Tags: node.js, child-process

Is there a way to kill the `child_process.exec()` from previous request by a new request  ex

I have part of code like so :

```
 var proc = require('child_process').exec('ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -o b.avi');
```

scenario like this

> request come -> check the exec() is running or not -> if running kill
>   it->run new exec() -> return !

is that possible to kill this running process by a new HTTP request?

is there a way to set an app status for Node.js and set a **flag**, then check the flag to stop the process?

Comment: It's all in the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html just use `proc.kill();`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can kill a child process by two ways.

**Solution 1:**
Use child process object with `kill()` function like

```js
proc.kill();
```

**Solution 2:**
Get process PID from child process and kill it by nodejs `process` anywhere in your application (execute kill action in HTTP request) like

```js
// Get process's pid and save it somewhere or global variable
let pid = proc.pid;
```

At next HTTP request comes, you can kill it by:

```
// Use node process to kill it anywhere by pid
process.kill(pid);
```

---

For your information, if you want to check a child process is running or not, try to check my question here [Nodejs how to check independently a process is running by PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285590/nodejs-how-to-check-independently-a-process-is-running-by-pid)

Comment: but the request is already return ,and the exec() sill running , i want to kill it went the next request come

Comment: You can save its PID of child process and kill it at next request comes as solution 2, I also updated my answer to help you understand it